# How do you use JSoup to find elements (HTML parsing)?

Tags: android, html-parsing, jsoup, element

I know that in Jsoup when you want to find a certain Element with a link in it, you can do this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(text); 
Element links = doc.select("[href]");
```

This however, takes all links to every website in the page...

But what if I have multiple links, and I only want to retrieve the ones specifically linking to google. For instance:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
<a href="http://www.bing.com">Bing</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com">Another Google</a>
```

And I want it to take only those with google in it. I tried doing something like this:

```
Element links = doc.select("[href=\"http://www.google.com\"]");
```

But this doesn't work... does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried simply this:

```
Element links = doc.select("[href=http://www.google.com]"); 
//Or,
Element links = doc.select("a[href=http://www.google.com]");

//Or with the 'attribute contains' form, the most likely to work:
Element links = doc.select("a[href*=google]");
```